# Xcode11, TableView Cell Selection Style doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

I uploaded the screenshot, I am setting the (static)tableview cell selection style to blue, but it doesn't work when I run the simulator, it is still the grey color. Then I tried the code cell.selectionStyle, but it also does not work. Am I doing wrong? or understanding wrong on this issue? I tried the code using ".contentView.backgroundColor" to set the background when I select or de-select a cell, it works,....but why the "cell.selectionStyle" does not work? AS I understand, it is right the background color when I select a cell.

Below is what(code) I tried to set the selection style. My focus is also on the interface as the picture showed.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("I select it")
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.selectionStyle = .blue
}
```

Comment: Add the relevant code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```swift
let backgroundView = UIView()
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
```

Comment: Yes, I know using backgroundColor can work. But why selectionStyle cannot work? Apple explains the selectionStyle is the default background color when user select a cell on the table view. I am very confused.